# Download documents with Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, browser, download

I am locally (wamp) developing a Symfony 2 application. I wanted to add the possibility to download some documentation thru the site.

I used this method in the controller :

```
public function downloadAction($filename = 'default_name') {
    $file = $filename . '.pdf';
    $path = realpath($this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . "/../doc/" . $file);
    return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse($path);
}
```

locally it works good but for Chrome for one document (dont know why).

When I copy the sources on a linux server, it works fine for Firefox with all the documents but with IE8 or Chrome one of the documents (the same one) does not download like it stops in the middle of it.

I tried to replace it several times in cas it was corrupted but it does the same thing.

Can you help ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no need to create a download action just in your twig template put the path to your file using the asset function in a link just like that `<a href="{{ asset('yourbundle/docs/filetodownload.pdf')}}">download</a>`

Comment: thank you for the tip... but if somebody has an answer to my question like it is, I would like to hear it

Comment: I just didn't understand why you want to use a download Action, what is the purpose of it?

Comment: @elkorchi anas. The usual reason to deliver a file through PHP is to provide access security. A direct link to the file means that the file needs to be publicly visible to the outside world directly via the web server. Of course there's a memory and performance cost to having it go through PHP.

Comment: but we can use isGranted() function in twig to, if it's just a security issue

Comment: Yeah but that, at best, only keeps the URL of the file a secret. With your suggestion, the file will still be available at something like http://example.com/bundles/yourbundle/docs/filetodownload.pdf. If someone can guess the URL then nothing in the application protects it. There are two parts to this. 1) Providing a link or not which is really just a UI thing and 2) Actually protecting the file.